# How can I make a function that finds the common elements of two strings?

Tags: haskell

I want to learn how to create functions using mainly head and tail. What I need to know is the protocol or presentation of elements, how to identify the elements, and how to define the function. For example, I am practicing how to write a simple function to find the common elements of two strings. Like this:

```
commonElt :: (Eq a)=> [a]->[a]-> bool

                commonElt [] _ = true
                commonElt _ [] = false
commonElt s1 s2 |if elm (head s1)s2 == true then show head s1 && commonElt(tail s1)s2
                |otherwise = commonElt(tail s1) s2
```

where `s1` and `s2` are strings. But I cannot load the modules because I get the following error message:  "parse error. possible incorrect identation."

Comment: I know nothing whatsoever of Haskell, but I'm going to hazard a guess based on the error message you received and the formatting of your code. If you copied and pasted your code snippet exactly, then I'd assume your code is indented the same as your code snippet. I wonder if perhaps you need to remove the indents before the two above lines? If that's not the case, I'd assume that your indentation is incorrect elsewhere. Either A) Run your eye over your code and make sure all the indentation is correct or B) If you're not sure what the correct indentation is, Google it and then fix your code.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: `julia`: Inevitably, what looks to be the same answer, from `hammar` appeared while writing, but maybe there is some helpful difference.

`julia`, as `larsmans` says, one problem is that you are not capitalizing the names of types and their constructors.  The definition of Bool is:

```
data Bool = True | False
```

the words on both sides are capitalized; `Bool` is the name of the type, `True` and `False` are the constructors we match on when dividing cases.  By contrast, if the new terms we define are functions and other values, we use lower case.  Suppose I want to define `not :: Bool -> Bool`, well there are two cases:

```
not True = False
not False = True
```

with `or :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool` there are four cases, but we can shorten things.

```
or False False = False
or _ _         = True
```

So here, `not` and `or` are both introduced with in lower case.  Now to get to your problem, the first thing to note is that the type signature and the first two cases,

```
commonElt :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
commonElt [] _ = True
commonElt _ [] = False
```

don't really correspond to your specification, which is to find the common elements. That would have the signature

```
commonElts :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

If we repair the first two lines to match that ambition we get

```
commonElts [] _ = []
commonElts _ [] = []
```

then, following the idea of your third case we can spare ourselves the use of `head` and `tail` if we note that in the case in question neither term will be constructed as `[]` but rather with `:`, so the case is, say:

```
commonElts (s:ss) (t:ts)
```

Your idea was to check whether `s` was in the second list, and then include it in a list that is built up by using `commonElts` on the remaining bit, `ss`. There are several ways of going about this, I will use `if`, following your example. Note that Haskell's `if...then..` is always `if ... then --- else ---`; the first blank is the boolean test, the other two blanks can be of any type as long as it is the same, thus we usually line them up:

```
commonElts (s:ss) (t:ts) = 
     if elem s (t:ts) == True then s : commonElts ss (t:ts)
                              else commonElts ss (t:ts)
```

Note. though, that `elem s (t:ts)` is already a Bool, True or False, so we don't need to add `== True`.  Furthermore, we don't actually use the division of the second list into `t` and `ts`, so we can just call it `ts` or `s2` as you did.  Thus the complete definition is:

```
 commonElts [] _ = []
 commonElts _ [] = []
 commonElts (s:s1) s2 = 
    if elem s s2 then s : commonElts s1 s2
                 else commonElts s1 s2
```

If an element appears more than once in the first list, it will appear more than once in the 'common element' list; we could resolve this with a further distinction of cases.

Edit:  note that a very similar function can be defined with a 'list comprehension':

```
common xs ys = [ x | x <- xs , y <- ys, x == y]
```

Comment: Nitpicking: With your definition of `or`, `or True False` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks `Tsuyoshi Ito`, I had I sense I was doing automatic typing there; I think it's right now.

Answer (score 3):

Indentation matters in Haskell. You should align the clauses for `commonElt`:

```
commonElt [] _ = true
commonElt _ [] = false
commonElt s1 s2 ...
```

Then realize that the boolean values are called `True` and `False`; Haskell is case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of errors here, and it's not clear exactly what your function should do, but here's an attempt to make some sense of it:

First, the lines definining `commonElt` should not be indented. Also, `Bool`, `True` and `False` are written with a leading upper case letter as they are constructors (`Bool` is a type constructor, `True` and `False` are data constructors).

Secondly, you don't use `if` in a guard like that. Just write the conditional on its own between the `|` and the `=`. Also, `== True` is uneccessary, and I think you meant to use `elem`, not `elm`.

The rest, while syntactically valid, does not type check or make much sense. `show` returns a `String` which cannot be used with `(&&)` because it only works on booleans (its type is `Bool -> Bool -> Bool`).

```
commonElt :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
commonElt [] _ = True
commonElt _ [] = False
commonElt s1 s2 | elem (head s1) s2 = show (head s1) && commonElt (tail s1) s2
                | otherwise = commonElt (tail s1) s2
```

At this point it's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but as you said in your problem statement that you were trying to find the common elements of two lists, I think you want something like this:

```
commonElt :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
commonElt [] _  = []
commonElt s1 s2 | elem (head s1) s2 = head s1 : commonElt (tail s1) s2
                | otherwise = commonElt (tail s1) s2
```

Instead of returning a `Bool`, we gather up a list of the elements in `s1` that are also in `s2` using the `(:)` operator which builds a list out of a head element and a tail list.

Of couse, this could be written more succinctly using higher order functions:

```
commonElt s1 s2 = filter (`elem` s2) s1
```

This function already exists in the `Data.List` module and is called `intersect`.

Comment: I put 'show' because I wanted to show each common elements.I am a little confuse because commonElt would be a list and 'head s1' is one element, then how is possible to put the operator (:) in front a list to join one element with a list.

Comment: @julia: Look at the type of `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. It prepends a single element to the start of a list. Compare with `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` which concatenates two lists.

Comment: @julia: As for showing the elements, it is usually best to have each function only do one thing, so if we first have a function that finds the correct elements, we can then use `show` or `print` on that list to convert it to a string or print it to standard output.